# SQL Server multiple values in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do you create a SQL query which counts the same value in the same column?

For example a customer can have multiple invoices with the same name but different ID.

So Carl has 2 invoices with the name Phone.

How would you use this in a query?

If I want to list the persons having 2 invoices with a specific name?

Comment: Post the table schema here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT invoicenumber,
       name,
       count
FROM   (SELECT invoicenumber,
               name,
               Count(1) AS count
        FROM   TABLE1
        GROUP  BY invoicenumber,
                  name)
WHERE  count = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard without the table schema but your query should look like this:

```
SELECT CustomerName from Invoice 
GROUP BY CustomerName,InvoiceName
HAVING COUNT(InvoiceName)>1
```

If you are using customer id you can join it first before grouping it and if you need to query a specific invoice you do it like this:

```
SELECT CustomerName from Invoice 
WHERE InvoiceName='Phone'
GROUP BY CustomerName,InvoiceName
HAVING COUNT(InvoiceName)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT name, count(invoices )
FROM table
WHERE name='Phone'
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(invoices) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you all customers that have at least two invoices with the name 'Phone':

```
select customer
from invoice
where invoice_name = 'Phone'
group by customer
having count(*) >= 2;
```